# Почему мне пишет что принято 5 параметров, если я принимаю и отсылаю только 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> TypeError: fight() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Непонимаю откуда Python взял 5 параметров, может кто-нибудь подсказать?

```
import random

class Warrior:
    health=0
    damage=0
    def __init__(self,health,damage):
        self.health=health
        self.damage=damage
    def fight(health1,damage1,health2,damage2):
        while (health1<=0) or (health2<=0):
            hod=random.random(1,2)
            if hod   ==   2:
                health1=health1-damage2
            if hod   ==   1:
                health2=health2-damage1

        if health1<=0:
            return 'Secondary Warrior win'
        else:
            return 'First Warrior win'

warrior1=Warrior(100,20)
warrior2=Warrior(100,20)
warrior=Warrior(0,0)

warrior.fight( warrior1.health,
               warrior1.damage,
               warrior2.health,
               warrior2.damage)
```

Comment: А self вы куда потеряли?

Comment: def fight(`self`, health1, damage1, health2, damage2):

Comment: учите ООП и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
warrior=Warrior(0,0)
warrior.fight(...)
```

Вы вызываете метод `fight` у **экземпляра** класса `Warrior`, а значит методу `fight` кроме переданных вами аргументов передаётся ещё первым аргументом ссылка на экземпляр класса, который обычно называют `self`. Так что вам нужно поменять описание метода:

```
def fight(self, health1,damage1,health2,damage2):
          ^^^^
```

Либо, если вам не нужны никакие поля экземпляра класса, то нужно вызывать метод `fight` у класса, а не у экземпляра:

```
Warrior.fight(...)
^ с большой буквы - имя класса, а не экземпляра
```